# How to update manually a pipeline in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, updates

Right now we are doing some tasks manually while the entire solution is prepared. One of this tasks is the updating process in some Resouce Groups. Normally, what we do is to export a template from our development environtment and, then we import that .zip file template. However, if the pipeline or other object are alredy present in the target ADF these are going to be created with the prefix 1.

[image]

Then we need to rename the objects (pipelines, data flows, data sets) to implement the new solution. We were wondering if there is a way to avoid this, or another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If both your Test_Pipeline or Test_Pipeline1 are going to perform similar type of actions then you can create a Dynamic pipeline using parameters in ADF and create a metadata / config for the operation that you need to perform and add a Lookup activity, that would avoid creating multiple pipelines

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity

Comment: Ok, thanks Patrik. We are going to take a look on that posibility.

Comment: Sure, let me know if it works or any other assistance needed and please mark it as answer if you think this solution worked :)